# How to output the inputted informations from one page to another page

Tags: php, javascript, html

Here is the complete code for rpay2.html

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="info" action="rpay4.php" method="get">
<h2>Personal Information</h2>
Name:
<input type="text" name="Name" value="Enter your name here" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)" class="txt" maxlength="99" onkeypress="return FilterInput (event)">

Address:
<input type="text" name="Address" value="Enter your address here" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)" class="txt" maxlength="99">

Contact #:
<input type="text" name="ContactNo" value="Enter your contact no. here" onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)" class="txt" maxlength="99">

E-mail:
<input type="text" name="Email" value="Enter your e-mail here " onfocus="ClearPlaceHolder (this)" onblur="SetPlaceHolder (this)" class="txt" maxlength="99">

<p align="right"><a href="rpay3.html"><input type="BUTTON" value="Submit" onclick="checkit(); return false"></a><a href="rpay.html" target="_top"><input Type="BUTTON" VALUE="Cancel"></a>
</div>
</form>
```

And for rpay4.php

```
<html>
<body>
Your reservation informations:
<br><br>
<?php
echo "Name: " . $_GET["Name"] . "";
echo "You live in " . $_GET["Address"] . "";
echo "Your contact number is " . $_GET["ContactNo"] . "";
echo "Your e-mail is " . $_GET["Email"] . "";
?>
<p align="right">Proceed?<br><a href="res.html" target="_top"><input     type="button" onclick="javascript:gosomewhere();" value="Ok"></a><input Type="BUTTON"     VALUE="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='rpay2.html'">
    </body>
</html>
```

Only "Your reservation informations:" and the button shows up in rpay4.php What seems to be the problem? Just a beginner, sorry

Comment: That looks okay. What is your question?

Comment: So, Whats the problem?

Comment: add a submit button and it should be OK.

Comment: Are you closing the form tag? </form>

Comment: The values from the textbox from rpay2.html didn't show in rpay4.php

Comment: Change
`<input type="BUTTON" value="Submit" onclick="checkit(); return false">` 
TO
`<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="checkit(); return false">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this

```
<p align="right"><a href="rpay3.html"><input type="BUTTON" value="Submit" onclick="checkit(); return false"></a><a href="rpay.html" target="_top"></a>
```

try this

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" onclick="checkit(); return false" /> <input Type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='rpay.html';" />
```

other than everything looks fine....